# Dot of semicolon

Tags: symbols

Is it possible to get a dot in the same position as the dot in the semicolon symbol? In other word I need only the dot of the semicolon symbol without the comma. The symbol `\cdot` is too low.

Comment: Hi, can you draw the symbol?...I have not understood that you have needed.

Comment: Maybe `\raisebox{3.3pt}{.}`?

Comment: You are probably looking for a _raised point_ in greek  `·` (Unicode U+0387).  It would help, if you could post some code

Comment: @Marijn: this seems to do the trick

Answer (score 5):

You want to raise the period by 1ex (the height of the lowercase letters, minus its height.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\anoteleia}{\raisebox{\dimexpr 1ex-\height\relax}{.}}

\begin{document}

abc\anoteleia\ def

;\anoteleia

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not in a hundred years would I have understood the symbol the user was asking for. :-)